# (Multiple) Axios Post requests/params question

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js, parameters, axios

This is a multipart question (and coincidentally my first here on Stack!). To preface, I'm building a site with a Rails backend and a Vue.js frontend.

My problem is with an Axios POST request. I am attempting to send **two** POST requests with one click of the submit button. I have a "Trips" controller and a "User_Trips" controller - the later of which functions as a join to other tables in my database. In order for a newly created trip to show up, a new user_trip needs to be created too.

My **trip** posts just fine and shows up when I look for it in Postico, but my user_trip does not post successfully, and I think it's because I'm struggling to determine how to pass the recently created trip's id through as the param needed to create a user_trip. Here is a section of the code I'm working on from Vue.js:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      trips: [],
      errors: [],
      name: "",
      country: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      postal_code: "",
      start_date: "",
      end_date: "",
      image: "", 
      trip: this.trip
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    // axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/trips").then(
    //   function(response) {
    //     console.log(response);
    //     this.trips = response.data.trips;
    //   }.bind(this)
    // );
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
      var params = {
        name: this.name,
        country: this.country,
        state: this.state,
        city: this.city,
        postal_code: this.postal_code,
        start_date: this.start_date,
        end_date: this.end_date,
        image: this.image
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/trips", params)
        .then(response => {
          axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/trips").then(
            function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              this.trips = response.data.trips;
            }.bind(this)
          );
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        });
      var paramsTwo = {
        trip_id: this.trip.id
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/usertrips", paramsTwo)
        .then(response => {
          this.$router.go("/home");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the error message I receive in the console log: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined** and I'm thinking it's because I'm not selecting the right trip from the array...BUT when I look at the GET request in the log, the newly created trip doesn't show up - it's only visible my database. Any helpful suggestions are most appreciated!! 
- Thanks

Comment: where are you updating your `this.trip`?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! A big thanks to the helpful commenters and answerers.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      trips: [],
      errors: [],
      name: "",
      country: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      postal_code: "",
      start_date: "",
      end_date: "",
      image: "", 
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function() {
      var params = {
        name: this.name,
        country: this.country,
        state: this.state,
        city: this.city,
        postal_code: this.postal_code,
        start_date: this.start_date,
        end_date: this.end_date,
        image: this.image
      };
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/api/trips", params)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.trip = response.data;
          var paramsTwo = {
            trip_id: this.trip.id
          };
          axios
            .post("http://localhost:3000/api/usertrips", paramsTwo)
            .then(response => {
              this.$router.go("/home");
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            });
        }
        );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is breaking at the `paramsTwo` line and that's why your second post won't work. Make sure that the object returned by your API has an id property. Some DBs return a _id property instead of id.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'm 95% confident saves as just "id" but it's strange that the newly created **trip** (i.e. the first POST) shows up in my DB but it doesn't show up in my console log anywhere even though I GET request it in multiple places. This join table is really messing with me haha

Comment: Then I'd go with @boussadjra-brahim's comment. From the info you posted, we can't see where `this.trip` is being updated. We can only see you handling `this.trips`